# the_meta - no get_the_meta query?

Tags: php, custom-field

I want to use `the_meta` as though it were `get_the_meta`. I want to do this because when i use `the_meta` in my `functions.php` file (I'm using a shortcode to enter data to pages), it posts the meta information to the top of the post as opposed to where I want it.

I have tried `get_the_meta`, but it doesn't seem to work and instead, it returns an error because it's obviously not a valid query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting an error because `get_the_meta` isn't a function. Just because many `the_*` functions have a corresponding `get_the_*` function, it doesn't mean that all do.

What you want is [`get_post_meta`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_meta) or [`get_post_custom`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_custom). Those will return arrays which you will have to loop over and format yourself. `the_meta` uses `get_post_custom`. You can [use its code](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.5.1/wp-includes/post-template.php#L742) as a template for your own code if you want.

Comment: Thanks. I used the code starting line 742, however it does the same as the_meta and posts the data to the top of the page, as opposed to where i want it to be. Essentially, i want to get the key and data from each entry of a post (and have it display where i want) and i'm not sure how to achieve that.

Comment: You can't use that code as is. You have to alter it. That is why I said "use it as a template" not "copy it wholesale". You need to build a string and `return` that, not `echo` it.

Comment: I understand that. I'm trying to set get_post_custom_values($key)

Comment: Why are you talking about _setting_ a value now? And if the code is still `echo`ing out of place after you have created a string and returned it, something is wrong somewhere else. Maybe [edit] your question to include your code.

Comment: Whoops. I sent that post by accident, you can disregard it. I started writing a message, decided not to post but somehow managed to post it. Sorry about that.